# What is wrong with my USACO Friday the Thirteenth solution?

Tags: java

From USACO Training Page, Friday the Thirteenth
The problem says to compute the frequency that the 13th will land on each day of the week for January 1, 1990 to December 31st, 1990+N-1, where N is given. January 1, 1990 is a Monday, and leap years are taken into account. The program should print the number of 13ths on Saturday, then number of 13ths on Sunday, etc down to Friday.
 I can't seem to find the problem in my code, and I've tried things for a couple days now. EDIT - You are not allowed to use date functions for the program
My output for N=20 is 37 34 35 34 36 36 35

It's supposed to be 36 33 34 33 35 35 34

```
import java.io.*;
class friday {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("friday.in"));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("friday.out")));

    int N = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    int[] monthDays = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

    int firstdayNo=2;
    int THIRdayNo;
    int[] counter = new int[8];
    Arrays.fill(counter, 1); 
    for (int j=1900; j<1900+N;j++) {
        if (j%4==0 && j%100 !=0 || j%400==0) { 
            monthDays[2]=29;
        }

        else {
            monthDays[2]=28;
        }



        for (int i=1; i<13; i++) {
            if (firstdayNo==2) {
                THIRdayNo=7;

            }
            else {
                THIRdayNo=(firstdayNo+12)%7; 
            }
            counter[THIRdayNo]++;
            firstdayNo= (monthDays[i]%7) +firstdayNo; 

            if (firstdayNo>7) {firstdayNo=firstdayNo-7;}
            // to here, and you are done
            }

    }
    out.println(+counter[7]+" "+ counter[1]+" "+counter[2]+" "+ counter[3]+ " "+counter[4]+" "+counter[5]+" "+counter[6]);
    in.close();
    out.close();
    System.exit(0);
}   

}
```

Comment: "should print number of Friday the 13ths on Saturday" something is wrong here: I can't imagine how come a Friday can happens on a Saturday.

Comment: Sorry, I justed fixed it

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Calendar` with the `GregorianCalendar` as the standard civil-date, already handles going from month to month (just use `Calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1)`), also keeps track of leap years and knows how to handle the DAY_OF_WEEK. So:

```
  static public void main(String[] arg) {
    int N=20;

    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> dayOfWeekOccurs=new TreeMap<>();
    // DAY_OF_WEEK is 1-based
    for(int dayOfWeek=1; dayOfWeek<=7; dayOfWeek++) {
      dayOfWeekOccurs.put(dayOfWeek, 0);
    }

    // month is 0-based, DAY_OF_MONTH is 1-based, YEAR is 0-based.
    // Consistency be damn'd.
    GregorianCalendar start=new GregorianCalendar(1990, 0, 13);
    GregorianCalendar end=new GregorianCalendar(1990+N-1, 11, 31);

    while(start.compareTo(end)<0) {
      start.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
      int dayOfWeek=start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
      int oldOccurs=dayOfWeekOccurs.get(dayOfWeek);
      dayOfWeekOccurs.put(dayOfWeek, ++oldOccurs);
    }

    System.out.println("13 on Sun: "+dayOfWeekOccurs.get(Calendar.SUNDAY)); 
    System.out.println("13 on Mon: "+dayOfWeekOccurs.get(Calendar.MONDAY)); 
    System.out.println("13 on Tue: "+dayOfWeekOccurs.get(Calendar.TUESDAY)); 
    System.out.println("13 on Wed: "+dayOfWeekOccurs.get(Calendar.WEDNESDAY)); 
    System.out.println("13 on Thu: "+dayOfWeekOccurs.get(Calendar.THURSDAY)); 
    System.out.println("13 on Fri: "+dayOfWeekOccurs.get(Calendar.FRIDAY)); 
    System.out.println("13 on Sat: "+dayOfWeekOccurs.get(Calendar.SATURDAY)); 
  }
```

Comment: I changed my explanation a bit - also you can't use date functions for the problem :(

Comment: @KabbageSenthilkumar too bad (whoever forbid you to do it has some sadistic inclinations) . Then I guess you can still use the technique to diagnose the problem with your code: make your code output the day of week for the 13th and use the Gregorian code to find when they get out of sync and diagnose why. (BTW, do try to use 0-based arrays, the code looks awkward with 1-based ones).